# Deleting raster file after doing some processing in QGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I run this script in my python console on QGIS:

```
import os
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

polygon_file = "E:/polygon.shp"
point_input = "E:/station.shp"
raster_output = 'E:/output_idw.tif'

layer = QgsVectorLayer(point_input, 'layer', 'ogr')
processing.runalg('grass7:v.surf.idw', layer, 8.0, 5.0, 'value', False, "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (110.5, 117, -9, -4.5), 0.001, -1.0, 0.0001, raster_output)
processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", raster_output, polygon_file, -1, False, False, False, 6, 0, 75, 1, 1, False, 0, False, "", 'E:/output_crop.tif')
os.remove(raster_output)
```

I need to delete the unclip raster file (raster_output) directly by doing "os.remove(raster_output)" after processing but it return 
`"[Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"`
What should i do so i can delete that file without exit QGIS?

Comment: Processing may load the result of processing algorithm. Is your raster in the result in the QGIS Layer Panel? Try to remove it with QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layer_id)

Comment: No it's not, there're no active layer on QGIS Layer panel @Zoltan

Comment: It is still loaded in the object raster_output and therefore locked. Delete raster_output first (del raster_output).

Comment: del raster_output
os.remove('E:/output_idw.tif')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'E:/output_idw.tif'

Comment: @Matte it still stuck and the file cannot be remove

Answer (score 5):

You could just make `raster_output` a *temporary* layer instead of writing it to disk. That way, you can avoid having to manually remove it. You can do this by assigning the output of `grass7:v.surf.idw` to `None` and then call the result as the input to the following algorithm.

So you could try something like this:

```
import os
import processing
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

polygon_file = "E:/polygon.shp"
point_input = "E:/station.shp"

layer = QgsVectorLayer(point_input, 'layer', 'ogr')
raster_output = processing.runalg('grass7:v.surf.idw', layer, 8.0, 5.0, 'value', False, "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (110.5, 117, -9, -4.5), 0.001, -1.0, 0.0001, None)
processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", raster_output['OUTPUT'], polygon_file, -1, False, False, False, 6, 0, 75, 1, 1, False, 0, False, "", 'E:/output_crop.tif')
```

Comment: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'selectedfeaturecount' see log for more details.. I've got that error..

Comment: @Faizalprabowo - Strange, I cannot reproduce your error as it works fine for me. Try adding `layer2 = QgsVectorLayer(polygon_file, 'layer2', 'ogr')` and then use `processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", raster_output['OUTPUT'], layer2, -1, False, False, False, 6, 0, 75, 1, 1, False, 0, False, "", 'E:/output_crop.tif')`

Comment: why after surf.idw process, the output.tif doesn't exist on temp directory so all script return "Wrong parameter value: " in raster_output['OUTPUT']

Comment: @Faizalprabowo - Have you tried saving it in another directory and not temp? Maybe even on the desktop (perhaps a permission issue)?

Comment: if i do that, what's the different with my question example above, actually i need to remove it

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with QGIS 3, by writing multiple times to a vector layer with "qgis:zonalstatistics" processing function.

The layer wasn't in the registry:

```
registryLayers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().keys()
legendLayers = [ layer.layerId() for layer in QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers() ]
layersToRemove = set( registryLayers ) - set( legendLayers )
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers( list( layersToRemove ) )
```

I removed the corresponding variable:

```
del(vectorlayer)
```

After these, I still couldn't delete the shapefile in explorer.
Finally, I solved it by removing globals:

```
for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith('_'):
        del globals()[name]
```

Then you need to reload some packages:

```
from qgis.core import *
import processing
```