# can't erase dbf and shp pyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I created a script in which I run numerous algorithms from `processing`. Each resulting layer is stored in a `shp` file. I just want to keep the final layer and delete the others, but when I want to erase them while QGIS is still open, they are still in usewhile not shown in the layers list, I can't erase them. This is a problem when I run my script a 2nd time because it doesn't work.

I tried removing the layers with 
`QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(layer.id())`
but I had no success so far...
`.prj .qpj` and `.shx` are deleted, only remains `.dbf` and `.shp`.

Here is the code

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *

layer=processing.getObject("carte")
layer.invertSelection()

processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', layer, "20","5",False, "c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/tampon+.shp")
processing.runalg('qgis:dissolve', "c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/tampon+.shp", True, None, "c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/dissolve.shp")

tampon=QgsVectorLayer("c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/tampon+.shp", 'finale','ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(tampon)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(tampon.id())

processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', "c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/dissolve.shp", "-20","5",False, "c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/carte_finale.shp")
dissolve=QgsVectorLayer("c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/dissolve.shp", 'finale','ogr')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(dissolve)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayer(dissolve.id())
layer = QgsVectorLayer("c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/carte_finale.shp", 'finale','ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: Yes, better add the full code ^^

Comment: Please use the `{}` formatting button on your code. The backlick is on intended for individual words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing an output for each algorithm (and then having to load and remove them), you can instead save them as temporary layers using the `None` parameter and call these as inputs for any subsequent algorithms. Not tested but the following should hopefully work:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *

layer=processing.getObject("carte")
layer.invertSelection()

tampon_plus = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', layer, "20","5",False, None)
dissolve = processing.runalg('qgis:dissolve', tampon_plus['OUTPUT'], True, None, None)
carte_finale = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', dissolve['OUTPUT'], "-20","5",False, "c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/carte_finale.shp")

layer = QgsVectorLayer("c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/carte_finale.shp", 'finale','ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: Well it works perfectly well for my script, but it doesn't answers the issue of files that can't be deleted whereas they are no longer in layer list... I will use your way from now, Thanks !

Comment: @Clement the best way for saying *thanks* here is accepting the answer (if it solved your issue or if it was the most useful for finding a solution).

Comment: @Clement - Most welcome! I have had trouble with similar problems in the past. Sometimes using `del layer` works after removing it from registry and then deleting the associated files like .dbf and .shp, other times it doesn't :)

Comment: If you still have the problem, try my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243520/deleting-raster-file-after-doing-some-processing-in-qgis/332442#332442